# Internet Explorer 9 randomly not entering the jQuery Ajax done callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, internet-explorer-9

I am using Typescript and jQuery ajax in a project. In one of the application pages (something like a dashboard) I have 15 grids, each of them with their WebApi calls and some additional calls to render some comboboxes. Besides this, in my app header I have other components which are requesting data for user and some other comboboxes. In the end, when I'm loading that specific page, the number of ajax calls will reach **24**.

Everything is working fine on Chrome, Mozilla and IE >= 10.
In IE9, it sometimes happens that **one specific call** from those 24 to not enter the ajax `done` callback. There is nothing special about this call. In network, the request for it is returning from backend with `status 200` , so it should enter the callback. The JSON received is valid, the ajax call is the same every time, but it's behaving differently.

If I remove all the other calls and leave only the problematic one, the issue does not occur anymore.

Does IE9 have problems with the number of ajax calls being made in a short period of time?

I am using Typescript and my function which is making the requests is below.

```
public Request(controllerActionName: string, method: string, data?: Object, headersData?: Object, countRequest: boolean = true) {
        let dataType = "json";
        let headers = _.extend({ "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, headersData);

        if (method === "DELETE") {
            dataType = "";
        }

        if (BaseWebApi.asyncRequestCount === 0 && countRequest) {
            PubSub.publishSync(OsiIDs.NotifyAsyncOperation, true);
        }
        console.log(controllerActionName + "/" + method + "  ---- prevCount: " + BaseWebApi.asyncRequestCount + "  ---- nextCount: " + (BaseWebApi.asyncRequestCount + 1));
        countRequest && BaseWebApi.asyncRequestCount++;
        let response = $.ajax({
            url: this.module + controllerActionName,
            method: method,
            headers: headers,
            contentType: (method.toLowerCase() === "get" ? "" : "application/json"),
            dataType: dataType,
            data: (method.toLowerCase() === "get" ? data : JSON.stringify(data))
        });

        response.done(() => {
            if (BaseWebApi.asyncRequestCount === 1 && countRequest) {
                PubSub.publishSync(OsiIDs.NotifyAsyncOperation, false);
            }
            console.log(controllerActionName + "/" + method + "  ---- prevCount: " + BaseWebApi.asyncRequestCount + "  ---- nextCount: " + (BaseWebApi.asyncRequestCount - 1));
            countRequest && BaseWebApi.asyncRequestCount--;
        }).fail((data, code, message) => {
            if (BaseWebApi.asyncRequestCount === 1 && countRequest) {
                PubSub.publishSync(OsiIDs.NotifyAsyncOperation, false);
            }
            console.log(controllerActionName + "/" + method + "  ---- prevCount: " + BaseWebApi.asyncRequestCount + "  ---- nextCount: " + (BaseWebApi.asyncRequestCount - 1));
            countRequest && BaseWebApi.asyncRequestCount--;
        });

        return response;
    }
```

Will binding the ajax calls solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seemed like IE9 has a default timeout when waiting for the server response.
So the server returned the responses, but the ajax `done` callback wasn't called because of this.

Specifying a bigger `timeout` when doing the ajax calls solved the issue.